# Java,writing console content to file

Tags: java

I am testing, trying to write the console content to file but when I run the app I the text file that was generated is empty. I want the user to enter some details when the user finished entering the details. I'd like the user to enter the filename to write the console content to. However, the file that was generated is empty.

```
public void test() {
    boolean check=true;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String name=Keyboard.readInput();
        System.out.println("Name:"+ name);
        System.out.println("Enter your age");
        int age=Integer.parseInt(Keyboard.readInput());
        System.out.println("Age:"+age);
    }

    out.println("enter 1 to save to file");
    int num=Integer.parseInt(Keyboard.readInput());
    if (num == 1) {
        out.println("Enter the file name to write to:\n");
        String filename = Keyboard.readInput();
        File myfile = new File(filename);

        try {
                PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(myfile));
                System.setOut(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is Keyboard class? It seems to not belong with native Java library.

Comment: You set the `System.out` to your file output stream at the very end, after you have done writing almost everything to `System.out`.  How is it supposed to redirect them to the file?  I strongly suggest you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate what you are trying to do

Comment: If you save the file from input user information, first you should implement the code that save the data to memory temporary.aIf you want to save the file from input user information, first you should implement the code that save the data to memory temporary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only create the file and not write anything on the file that's why file is empty. After Creating a file you have to write something on the file via `PrintStream.println()` method.

```
try {
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(myfile));
    out.println("some text"); // it will write on File

    // OR if you setOut(PrintSrtream) then
    System.setOut(out);
    System.out.println("some text");// this will also write on file
} catch (IOException e) {
    out.println("Error:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8+

```
static void writeFile(String path, String...lines) throws IOException {
    Files.write(
        Paths.get(path), 
        Arrays.asList(lines));
}
```